# Dynamically Updating Function

Tags: functions, dynamic, inputfield

I use Mathematica 8 and am working with DynamicModule. I'm trying to enter a function in an InputField then later apply it to two values entered in subsequent Input Fields. The function just does not seem to be dynamically applying to the new values I input. The issue probably lies in my definition of the function.

```
     DynamicModule[{dydx = Null, xi = Null, yi = Null}, 
      Deploy[
       Panel[
        Grid[Transpose[{{"Differential equation: (dy/dx)=", "x:", "y:", 
        "slope:"}, {InputField[Dynamic[dydx]], InputField[Dynamic[xi]],
        InputField[Dynamic[yi]], 
        InputField[
          Dynamic[Function[{x, y}, Dynamic[dydx]][Dynamic[xi], 
           Dynamic[yi]]], Enabled -> False]}}]]]]]
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of issues here:

1. There is no need to wrap `Dynamic` around the inner variables of the final input field expression.  Indeed, it is harmful as `Dynamic` is purely a user interface element and acts as a holding wrapper in any other context (like an arithmetic expression).
2. The use of `Function` in the output expression will cause the variables `x` and `y` to be localized.  However, an use of those variables in the equation field will refer to the symbols in the surrounding context (probably `` Global` ``).

We can fix both of these problems thus:

```
DynamicModule[{dydx = Null, xi = Null, yi = Null}
, Deploy @ Panel @ Grid @ Transpose @
    { { "Differential equation: (dy/dx)=", "x:", "y:", "slope:"}
    , { InputField[Dynamic[dydx]]
      , InputField[Dynamic[xi]]
      , InputField[Dynamic[yi]]
      , InputField[Dynamic[dydx /. {x -> xi, y -> yi}], Enabled -> False]
      }
    }
]
```

Note how the role of `Function` has been taken over by a replacement expression.  We could have still used `Function` by "hiding" it from the variable-renaming machinery, e.g.

```
Dynamic[(Function@@{{x, y}, dydx})[xi, yi]]
```

But I prefer the simpler replacement expression shown above.

Another possible issue concerns the expressions entered by the user.  The user's input is changed ("simplified") when focus leaves each input field.  This may or may not be what you want.  To disable it, change the expression type for the field to be `Boxes`.  Any use of the field's value must interpret that value using `ToExpression`.  For example, applying this adjustment to the equation field:

```
DynamicModule[{dydx = Null, xi = Null, yi = Null}
, Deploy @ Panel @ Grid @ Transpose @
    { { "Differential equation: (dy/dx)=", "x:", "y:", "slope:"}
    , { InputField[Dynamic[dydx], Boxes]
      , InputField[Dynamic[xi]]
      , InputField[Dynamic[yi]]
      , InputField[Dynamic[ToExpression@dydx /. {x -> xi, y -> yi}], Enabled -> False]
      }
    }
]
```

[image: screenshot of the panel]

Without the use of `Boxes`, the user's expression `Sin[x] / Cos[y]` gets changed to `Sec[y] Sin[x]` as soon as the cursor leaves the field.

Comment: Excellent! The substitution worked well. New problems have arisen though